# Verilog 16 bit overflow for 32 bit reg

Tags: verilog

I have declared two input [32:0] ports in1,in2 and an output reg [32:0] out

in the always block, the code goes as follows:
out=in1+in2;

now it works fine for add, but when in1=0 and in2=-1, out is always 0x0000ffff instead of 0xffffffff

I tried declaring integer [32:0] types but I don't think am doing it properly.

(transcribed from comment:)

```
module adder(out, in1, in2, sub);
output reg[31:0] out;
input [31:0] in1, in2;
input [4:0] sub;

always @(*) begin
 case (sub)
  `ALU_ADD: begin out=alutemp1+alutemp2; //out=in1+in2;
   $display("in1 %x and in2 %x and out %x\n",in1,in2,out);
 end
end
```

Please advice,
Thanks

Comment: Can you show your real code?

Comment: The code is as follows
module adder(out, in1, in2, sub);
   output reg[31:0] out;
   input [31:0]  in1, in2;
   input  [4:0]  sub;
always @(*)
 begin
  case (sub)
   `ALU_ADD: begin
out=alutemp1+alutemp2;
       //out=in1+in2;
       $display("in1 %x and in2 %x and out %x\n",in1,in2,out);
       end
      end

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your adder works fine (since it's not compilable in a software that I'm using). But if you change code to something like this:

```
module Verilog1(out, in1, in2, sub);
output reg[31:0] out;
input [31:0] in1, in2;
input [4:0] sub;

always @(*) 
  begin
    out <= in1 + in2;
    $display("in1 %x and in2 %x and out %x\n",in1,in2,out);
  end 
endmodule
```

For inputs `in1 = 0` and `in2 = -1` you get `0xffff_ffff`.